# Apache Rejecting Requests

Tags: apache2

I have tried to add some stuff to my web server, http://37.187.57.12/ < Test it

and it gives you a connection refused error. I've checked UFW, Enabled port 80, 8080, 443 in it, etc, What else is the problem? What's wrong?

Comment: Assuming you're running this on your local machine have you tried connecting with `localhost` and you say you've enabled those ports, but where and did you do it correctly? We need more information

Comment: Not running on my local machine, Ports 80 8080 443 are enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran `nmap -PN 37.187.57.12` and the results were

```
Host is up (0.25s latency).
Not shown: 995 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
21/tcp   closed ftp
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   closed http
3306/tcp closed mysql
8080/tcp closed http-proxy
```

So try to open the ports on your router.